# What's the best way to renumber these MATLAB column elements?

Tags: matlab

I have a column which contains values in ascending order (e.g. 18, 25, 42, 18, 18, 42, 25).

I want to renumber all these values so that they represent their rank order. Thus all the 18s should turn into 1s, all the 25s should turn into 2s, all the 42s should turn into 3s.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: see `doc unique` (the third output argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
>> [x,~,ind] = unique([18, 25, 42, 18, 18, 42, 25])
x =
    18    25    42
ind =
     1
     2
     3
     1
     1
     3
     2
```

Comment: +1 - You beat me to it!

Comment: @rayryeng: I'm sure this question has been asked before! Can you find a possible duplicate?

Comment: Duplicate found.  Feel free to verify and close.

Comment: I found an older one. Both apply :)

Comment: That's a better one than what I linked to.  Nice find Amro!

Comment: you know it's funny sometimes it's just faster to answer the question than to look for the duplicates! We need a better search engine on SO..

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more Amro.  It's frustrating when you've seen something similar, yet can't quite remember where you've found it on SO.  The search mechanisms for duplicates is pretty bad IMHO (and I see you also agree).  They need to improve the search mechanism!